Mixed effect linear regression reverse X and Y
Suppose I fit a mixed effect linear model with random intercept and slope with $Y$ as the response and $X_1, X_2, \dots$ as fixed effects.
$$y_i = \beta_0 + \beta_1 x_{i,1} + \beta_2 x_{i,2} + \cdots + u_i + \epsilon_i,$$
where $\epsilon\sim\mathcal{N}(0,\sigma^2)$, $u_i$ is the random intercept subject to $i^{\text{th}}$ individual, $y_i$ and $x_{i,j}$ is $n_i\times 1$ response and predictors vector respectively for all $i\leqslant N$ and $j\leqslant q$.
My question is, once I fit the model and obtain the coefficients. Can I do some linear transformation, such that when I obtain new $y_i$, I can use them to predict $x_{i,1}$, i.e.
$$\hat x_{i,1} =\frac{y_i-\beta_0 -\beta_2 x_{i,2} - \cdots-u_i}{\beta_1}.$$
Moreover, if I fit a new model with $X_1$ as response with $Y$ and $X_2,\dots,X_q$ as predictors, is the new coefficients a linear combination of the old ones.
I don't want to consider overfitting here.

Simplifying this, regressing $Y$ against $X_1$ will give you different results compared to regressing $X_1$ against $Y$ (assuming their correlation is not $\pm1$).  Try with some toy data.

If the results are different, would it be invalid to use the old coefficients to predict $X_1$? If the nature of $Y$ is a function of $X_1$, should I fit a new model with $X_1$ as response and $Y$ as predictor?
